# If an input field has got tags or java code

Tags: jquery

I have got a form in my HTML code

```
<input id="my-input" type="text" value="<div><p>Hello World</p></div>">
<input type='submit'>
<p id="result"></p>
```

And would like to prevent sending / disable submission any html tags or java code from this forms by using jQuery.

```
var inputText = $('#my-input').val();
inputText = $(inputText)[0].textContent;
$('#result').html(inputText);
```

Please find the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3c2doLw4/

Could any bode advice and change my JSfiddle?

My PHP code to add info into MySQL is looking like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `content`(`title`, `article`, `author`, `date`) VALUES ('[val1]', '[val2]', '[val3]', '[val4]')";
$result = $wpdb->query($query);
```

Comment: I use strip_tags() in php

Comment: this is my code in php:   

$query = "INSERT INTO.....";   

$result = $wpdb->query($query);

Can you please tell me where shall I add strip_tags();

Comment: probably before you make $query. Can you show me more code?

Comment: it seems like your code is working fine on fiddle, trims off the html tags. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz I need to disable Submit button or prevent it on the server via PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but you can check if the string contains `<` or `>`, then if it does, prevent the submission on the front end:

```
  var originalInputText = $('#my-input').val();
  if(originalInputText.indexOf('<') > -1 || originalInputText.indexOf('>') > -1){
      $('#result').html('Contains invalid text!');
      //prevent from form submitting
  }
  else{
      $('#result').html('VALID');
  }
```

Here is simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3c2doLw4/3/

Comment: Thank you @CanerAkdeniz Would it be possible just to disable and hide the submit button and add a css class to the field so people won't be able to submit any code...

Comment: Thank you  @CanerAkdeniz is it possible also to check that my input field's value is not empty or started with space and hide it as it would have < or > with keyup

Comment: Come on, seems like you are making me all the job for you. It should be fairly easy, try it by yourself first.

Comment: I know it sounds like I am lazy but tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/3c2doLw4/9/ and it didn't work for some reasons....Please help me last time...

Comment: here, this should include all the cases you wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/3c2doLw4/10/

Comment: I really appreciate your help and guidance on this problem. @CanerAkdeniz you are super developer and helped me (and probably other people) to understand jQuery a little bit more.